# C# Task, where do I need to catch a SystemAggregateException

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to understand where I need to use try/catch blocks.  Is it safe to only put a try/catch around Task.WaitAll() below, or do I have to surround each Task with a try/catch, as well as the Task.WaitAll()?

```
Task<SomeResult> myTask1 = DoSomethingAsync1();
myTask1.ContinueWith(x => 
{
   // Do something here;
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

Task<SomeResult> myTask2 = DoSomethingAsync2();
myTask2.ContinueWith(x => 
{
   // Do something here;
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

// Some other code that executes while these tasks are running
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

Task.WaitAll(myTask1, myTask2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating task will not call an exception. Exception handling is performed during retrieval of information thus when you wait for results. And this is the proper place to handle exceptions and the only place you should bother doing so.

Comment: But, a continuation task can use the result of a Task (`x.Result`).  If I gave these continuation Tasks a name (`contTask1, contTask2`), and only surrounded `Task.WaitAll(contTask1, contTask2);` with a try/catch, wouldn't accessing `x.result` inside of a continuation task be able to throw an exception as well?

Comment: @blgrnboy You are providing a delegate there. You are acutally not invoking this code in the moment it is being executed. It will be done on other thread and you will get the result of it when you wait it. Continuation means that you are telling what should be executed after finishing one part of computation without actually caring whether it will be successful or not. You will find it later when you wait it.

Comment: @blgrnboy Yes, it will throw an exception but you will capture it only when you wait a task.

Comment: Ok, so should I be performing a Task.Wait() on the main tasks (myTask1 and myTask2)?  Does this execute all continuation tasks associated with each?  Or would I have to create variables for the last continuation tasks sequentially, and await those?

Comment: You have specified that the **ContinueWith** delegate should execute **OnlyOnRunToCompletion**.  So, if it throws an exception that **ContinueWith** will not execute.  As you have it defined, the code, **Task.WaitAll** will throw the exception.  You can specify another **ContinueWith** using **OnlyOnFaulted** to catch any exception.